# Magento отображение схожих продуктов по атрибуту

Tags: list, magento

​
У меня имеется магазин работающий на Magento 1.7.2
Моя цель это на странице продукта в секции related products автоматически отображать продукты от этого же производителя, сортированные от новых к старым.

Первой идеей было воспользоваться уже написанным плагином, но после последовательной установки нескольких был выявлено что у таковых есть значительное ограничение, они подтягивают продукты из такой же категории без дополнительных опций.

Второй идеей была идея о возможности отредактировать файл активной темы для страницы продукта и заменить оригинальную секцию для схожих продуктов на php подтягивающий последние 5 продуктов от бренда продукта на странице. Но тут возникает другая проблема с малыми знаниями в Magento.

Имеется ли более простой вариант решения проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут я думаю есть два варианта.

1. Переписать код получения релейтед продуктов, чтобы получать товары не зависимо от категории + выбрать по производителю.
2. Написать выборку самому, например получить коллекцию товаров, отфильтрованную по значению текущего производителя потом, отсортировать и определить лимит для коллекции.

пример по второму варианту:

```
protected $_productCollection;

public function getSublings()
{
    $_productCollection = $this->getProductCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('brand',array('eq' => '1'))
            ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId());

    $_productCollection->getSelect()
                       ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'))
                       ->limit(5);

    return $_productCollection;
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    $categoryId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

    $this->_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreId())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId);

    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInSearchFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);
    Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($this->_productCollection);

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

В примере:

Два метода один получает коллецию продуктов + цены, в наличии и т.д., второй метод используюя эту коллекцию фильтрует её по атрибуту brand (допустим что значение атрибута  = 1) и лимитирует коллекцию до пяти продуктов.

Как-то так.

Comment: Второй вариант это именно то что я использовал в конечном варианте, я использовал `$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')` для получения бренда с страницы на которой находимся и путем подбора выдавал схожие продукты, код можно посмотреть тут https://github.com/antonk52/magento-related-products-by-brand/blob/master/related.phtml

Comment: 1. Не знаю полной реализации, но, категорически не советую выполнять обращение к модели, выборку коллекций и т.д. в самом шаблоне, это нужно делать в блоке а в самом шаблоне просто получать результат.

2. Так же вот например вместо $currentProductName != $_product->getName() советую использовать сразу  при выборке вот это $_products->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq' => 'ид твоего продукта'));

3. Еще момент для получения ИД атрибута - $option_id = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($product_id, $attribute_code, $store_id);

Comment: по какой причине этого не стоит делать?

Comment: Причин несколько.

1. Это не безопасно.
2. Не соответствует стилю Мадженто.
3. Не соответствует паттерну MVC т.к. во вь.хе только отдаем параметры и принимаем данные уже готовые для работы.
4. Это не удобно. много лишнего кода в вьюхе.
5. ООП, наследование и т.д. Представми что нам нужн ов нашем модуле получать коллекцию 4 раза для разных блоков, пишем собственный класс абстракт, в нем делаем основную реализацию, например получние основной отфильрованной коллекции и наследуем его в наших четырех блоках, а там уже фильруем и режем коллекцию как нам нужно для каждого отдельно.

Comment: Вот неплохой ресурс еще - http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/addattributetofilter/

Comment: Полный ответ, спасибо за приложенный ресурс, обязательно приму к сведению и изменю подход к этому, спасибо